# Configure Android Studio Warning dialogs

Tags: android-studio

Android studio show alert or warning dialog like below :

[image]

After cancel it again popup infinite times and not able to close these warning permanently. Is there any configuration in android studio to stop showing these warning alerts.

Comment: Why don't you click on the "Fix it" link in the message and enter the correct path to git.exe in the settings dialog which is shown when you click it?

Comment: this is just example there are few warning which stay there

Comment: Normally, when an IDE shows you a warning, it tells you that something about your project is not configured correctly. If you understand the warning and fix your project configuration, this will give you a much better IDE experience than if you just ignore it or find a way to turn it off.